# User Login is not working with node.js and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to user login with node.js and mongoose.
User Registration is successfully working and data is inserting in mongodb collection, but when I try to login with registered email and password the page show 404 error.

**login.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/login', function(req, res, next){
user.findOne({email:req.body.email}, function(err, user){
  if(!user){
    res.render('login',{title:'Invalid'});
  }
  else{
    if(req.body.password===user.password){
      res.render('/dashboard',{title:'Success Fully login'});
    }
    else{
      res.render('login',{title:'invalide password'});
    }
  }
});
});

module.exports = router;
```

**login.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>

  <div style="margin:0 auto ; width:50%; padding:20px">
    <form action="/login"  method="post">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email">
      <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
    <label>Pass</label>
    <input type="text" name="password">
      <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
    <button>Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which page gives 404? `/` or `/login`?

Comment: After click on login button its redirected to  http://localhost:3000/login and shows Not Found

404

Error: Not Found
    at d:\ANGULAR JS\WebstormProjects\uDatabase\app.js:45:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (d:\ANGULAR JS\WebstormProjects\uDatabase\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (d:\ANGULAR JS\WebstormProjects\uDatabase\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)

Comment: Can't see anything _obvious_ wrong. How do you add the exported route to express?

Comment: have u used any password encryption in registration

Comment: No, I did not use any password encryption

Comment: Tip: do not use simple `===` when checking passwords, use a constant time comparison to prevent timing attacks.

Comment: Can you plz tell me how to use constant time comparison? @mscdex

Comment: log req.body.email and password and check wheather you are reciving valid values with no whitespace involved and in render use 'dashboard' instead of '/dashboard'

Answer (score 0):

You specify in your router that login page can only be accessed with POST query. But then you redirect your user to `/login` page, you make a GET query, thats why you get 404.