# Redirect to different HTML page on click of a button when match is found in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mongodb, express

I am learning web-designing and trying to make a simple customer detail maintenance application using javascript, mongodb, express and ajax.

The first page of my app has user 'login' and 'registration' buttons.
On click of 'registration' button I take control to a different page (by using href = "page.html" command in html), where user enters all his personal details. which are stored in mongoDB database ( I am able to implement this feature).

Now, I want to implement feature for 'login' button wherein on entering a  'username' and 'password' and on click of the button, first details are checked in the database if present or not. If details are not present then an error message is displayed and control stays on the screen (this feature also I am able to implement successfully).

I am stuck in implementing the successful case, wherein if details of the user are found in the database and login button is clicked. For this scenario, I want to take control to a new page which will display all the customer details that were stored during 'registration' phase.

Pardon me for my noob status in web technologies.
Will appreciate if someone can guide with code snippets or relevant technique to implement this feature.

Comment: Personal opinion: At such a low knowledge level, you should stay wide away from trying to implement your own login solution right now. That is way too complex a topic, to be handled properly with what you seem to know so far. Asking for general recommendations on books or tutorials is off-topic here. You need to go and learn some of the relevant basics yourself first.

Comment: And you call yourself a "noob" (what is for sure not a problem, then we all started from nothing) but you use too many technologies together when you probably can do it with 1-2, and as @CBroe said, implementing your own login logic is not that easy as it might sound.

Comment: for nnod lvl try like that `if(response){ location.href="home.html"}else{ alert(" Wrong login Details ")} ` :p

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am trying to make a simple CRUD application. Pardon me if the word 'Login' indicated something over the roof stuff. I am not trying to make some hi-tech login stuff in my initial attempt. My requirement is pretty much straight, I guess, on click of a button, search for a given record in database, if found then get its details and display on a different html page.

Comment: @tanmay try this question `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35263461/user-login-is-not-working-with-node-js-and-mongoose`